# open onedrive folder or folder within folder in onedrive ios app using another ios application

Tags: ios, windows, xamarin, onedrive

We are developing one mobile application in xamarin and trying to open a onedrive application folder from our application.
we are opening one drive application from our application using:

```
"ms-onedrive://sites"
```

but we can't open a folder or folder in folder .

We have already tried different methods listed below,

```
ms-onedrive://folder/foldername

ms-onedrive://sites/folder/foldername
```

Comment: Can you open the onedrive application?

Comment: yes We can open application using "ms-onedrive://sites/folder/foldername" but we can not open a specific folder or file.

Comment: Yes, We can open onedrive application using "ms-onedrive://sites" but we need to open specific folder using URL